# Property 'shouldComponentUpdate' is not assignable to the same property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got an error in TypeScript using `shouldComponentUpdate`:

> Property 'shouldComponentUpdate' in type 'Hello' is not assignable to the same property in base type `Component<IProps, any, any>`.

in Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Hello extends Component<IProps, any> {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: IProps) { // error here
    console.log(nextProps, 'nextProps')
  }

  ....// some code
}
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a little bit annoying to use React with TypeScript, because the last one today is does not contains all required error describing tips. So, probably an error in your case is binded with non-finished `return` call from `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

Try next and see what will happen:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: IProps) { // error here
    console.log(nextProps, 'nextProps')
    return true
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's help me!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is due to the fact that `shouldComponentUpdate` is expected to return a boolean. You are returning `void` because you are not explicitly returning anything. The default is to return true, so merely adding that as your final statement in the function fixes the issue.

For more information, see for example the react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript expects you to define the type each of the passed parameters and the type of the `return`ed value. If your function does not have a return statement then you can use `: void`.

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: IProps): void {
    console.log(nextProps, 'nextProps')
  }
```